STM32CubeIDE debugger no longer works in macOS 15.0 Sequoia
STM32CubeIDE fails in macOS 15.0 Sequoia when trying to run the debugger. The message is "ST-Link Server is required to launch the debug session. Please download it on www.st.com." This is on an M2 Mac using the latest STM downloads.
This has been reported on the STM32 forum but the solution suggested there is "Apparently launching the app from the terminal with sudo solves this, so it appears to be a permissions issue."
I am reluctant to run 3 GBytes of IDE, from outside the app store, with root permissions. Does anyone have any better insight into this bug? Am I being too picky?
I uninstalled STM32CubeIDE entirely, including the settings in Library, and reinstalled it, v 1.16.1, and no change.
Update: Yes it is the PATH available to the app that is the problem, exactly as pyrho suggested.
I asked chatGPT to explain how to find the PATH of a running GUI app. Following those instructions, I typed at a terminal
ps aux | grep STM

and that told me the PID of the running STM32CubeIDE process, that I'd started by clicking on the app icon. It's the number after the username. Then I typed
ps eww <PID> | grep PATH

where <PID> was the PID I found in the previous step. That told me (among other things) that PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin which notably does not include /usr/local/bin where the stlink-server lives. Despite the PATH entry in the app's info.plist file.
I tried all this with pyrho's solution of launching the app from my command line. My PATH does include /usr/local/bin. And the ps tricks above did tell me that the running app did have it in the PATH. However, on hitting debug in the app, it told me "No ST-LINK detected! Please connect ST-LINK and restart the debug session."
So then I tried another chatGPT suggestion. I wrote a shell script launchstm:
#!/bin/bash
# Modify the PATH to include /usr/local/bin
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

# Launch the actual executable within the .app bundle
/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/STM32CubeIDE &

I did chmod +x launchstm and made sure it was in my PATH. Type launchstm at the terminal and that did actually work. It found my ST_LINK and I can debug again.
Great thanks to pyrho who gave me the hint. I have no idea why his proposed solution didn't work for me, but it put me on the right $PATH.

Had the same issue, you don't need to sudo.
It seems to be a $PATH issue, my stlink-server is located under /usr/local/bin I guess for some reason the update made it so that Applications do not have this path in their $PATH environment.
To locate your stlink-server installation, in a terminal, run $ locate stlink-server, make sure that path is in your $PATH environment variable, then launch Cube: /Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/STM32CubeIDE.
Works for me.

Very plausible, thanks, but when I right-click /Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app and choose "Show Package Contents" and open the info.plist there, there is already an environment variable PATH which includes /usr/local/bin, and it still fails. And /usr/local/bin is in my $PATH too.

You're right, me too. Perhaps something changed in macOS 15 that breaks the LSEnvironment plist key.

For the record, STM32CubeIDE does not yet (as of 2024-09-23) support macOS15. See https://community.st.com/t5/stm32cubeide-mcus/bug-stm32cubeide-won-t-connect-to-st-link-v2-debugger-on-macos/m-p/722161#M30826

This solution is working for me.

Locate the stlink-server File: Run the following command in the terminal to find where stlink-server is installed:


locate stlink-server
2. It will return paths like /usr/local/bin/stlink-server.
3. For bash (default in older macOS versions):
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
4. For zsh (default in macOS Catalina and later):
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
5. Launch STM32CubeIDE with Correct Path: Use the terminal to launch STM32CubeIDE manually:


/Applications/STM32CubeIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/STM32CubeIDE


Ni Nicolas. Did you by any chance create this answer using an AI assistant (like ChatGPT)?
